# Where is the GUVCVIEW configuration file?

Tags: webcam

I had GUVCVIEW working once before. it suddenly quit working. 
This is the error I receive........

```
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
video device: /dev/video0 
/dev/video0 - device 1
Init. Intergrated Webcam (location: usb-0000:00:1a.7-2)
{ pixelformat = 'YUYV', description = 'YUV 4:2:2 (YUYV)' }
{ discrete: width = 640, height = 480 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 352, height = 288 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 320, height = 240 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 176, height = 144 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 160, height = 120 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1024, height = 768 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/9, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 1024 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/9, 1/5, 
checking format: 1196444237
Format unavailable: 1196444237.
Init v4L2 failed !! 
Init video returned -2
trying minimum setup ...
video device: /dev/video0 
/dev/video0 - device 1
Init. Intergrated Webcam (location: usb-0000:00:1a.7-2)
{ pixelformat = 'YUYV', description = 'YUV 4:2:2 (YUYV)' }
{ discrete: width = 640, height = 480 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 352, height = 288 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 320, height = 240 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 176, height = 144 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 160, height = 120 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/30, 1/20, 1/15, 1/10, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1024, height = 768 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/9, 1/5, 
{ discrete: width = 1280, height = 1024 }
    Time interval between frame: 1/9, 1/5, 
checking format: 1448695129
Requested Format unavailable: get width 640 height 480 
vid:0c45 
pid:6410 
driver:uvcvideo

(guvcview:4079): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_hscale_new_with_range: assertion `min < max' failed

(guvcview:4079): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_scale_set_draw_value: assertion `GTK_IS_SCALE (scale)' failed
Segmentation fault
```

I suppose the problem lies in the fact, that I cannot locate a configuration file to edit. Any help in where this file may lie? I have tried searching for any/everything related to guvcview, and have had zero success.

Thank you for taking the time to read this, and hopefully providing a solution..

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is wrong, or at least out of date. For the version of guvcview currently in the ubuntu repositories (1.7.1), the configuration files are written to:

```
~/.config/guvcview/videoN
```

where videoN corresponds to the device (/dev/video0, /dev/video1, ...)

Comment: Copying the  old `~/.guvcviewrc` file to the new `~/.config/guvcview/videoN` location indeed fixed the error message in the question for me.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from [Official Documentation](http://guvcview.sourceforge.net/Doc.html):

> Guvcview stores all options into a configuration file named
>   .guvcviewrc, this file is stored in the user home directory. The file
>   is opened at start and it is rewritten at exit. By removing the file
>   the default values will be loaded, and a new file will be written at
>   exit.

You can specify config file using *-g* option